# Calculate number of intersecting values between one data frame column and all columns of other data frames

Tags: r, database, dplyr

I have some tables that I've extracted from a database via `RODBC`. The first has a primary key field `__ID`.

```
dfA  <- data.frame(
`__ID` = c("a1","a2","a3"), 
col=c(1,2,3), 
check.names = FALSE )

  __ID col
1   a1   1
2   a2   2
3   a3   3
```

And the second has foreign key fields that start with `_ID`.

```
dfB  <- data.frame(
"_ID0" = c("z1", "z2", "z3"), 
"_ID1" = c("a1", "b1", "c1"), 
`_ID2` = c("a1", "a2", "c1"), 
`_ID3` = c("a1", "a2", "a3"), 
check.names = FALSE  )

  _ID0 _ID1 _ID2 _ID3
1   z1   a1   a1   a1
2   z2   b1   a2   a2
3   z3   c1   c1   a3
```

I would like to produce the following data frame which has the names of the two tables above and has all pairwise combinations between the primary key field from the first table and the foreign key fields from the other table. For each pair, it shows the number of intersecting values in a column called `intersects`.

```
matches  <- data.frame(
pk_table = "dfA", 
pk=c("__ID", "__ID","__ID","__ID"), 
fk_table= c("dfB", "dfB","dfB","dfB"), 
fk=c("_ID0", "_ID1", "_ID2", "_ID3"), 
intersects=c(0, 1,2,3), 
check.names = FALSE )

  pk_table   pk fk_table   fk intersects
1      dfA __ID      dfB _ID0          0
2      dfA __ID      dfB _ID1          1
3      dfA __ID      dfB _ID2          2
4      dfA __ID      dfB _ID3          3
```

Here's an example of how a single value for the `intersects` column could be calculated. The value 1 is returned because the `__ID` column has one value that's also found in `_ID1`.

```
length( intersect(dfA$`__ID`, dfB$`_ID1`) )
```

How can I create the above without loops? I would ideally like to have a solution that accepts the following inputs:

- table name and column name of primary key field
- all additional data structures (`dfB`, `dfC`, etc)

The function should then count all matches between the primary key field and all other columns of all other data structures provided. In total, my database has 700 columns in 15 tables. My primary key field is in one table and I would like to count how many times the values in this column occur in each of the columns of all 15 tables (including the same table in which it is found). I cannot assume that the foreign key columns follow a particular naming convention, but the total amount of data in the database is less than 50MB so I don't expect performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

options(stringsAsFactors = F)

dfA  <- data.frame(
  `__ID` = c("a1","a2","a3"), 
  col=c(1,2,3),
  check.names = FALSE )

dfB  <- data.frame(
  fk_table = c("dfB", "dfB","dfB"), #added a column with the table name
  `_ID0` = c("z1", "z2", "z3"), 
  `_ID1` = c("a1", "b1", "c1"), 
  `_ID2` = c("a1", "a2", "c1"), 
  `_ID3` = c("a1", "a2", "a3"), 
  check.names = FALSE  )

dfB%>%
  # first we gather the dataframe to long, tidy format
  gather(key = fk, value = value, `_ID0`:`_ID3`)%>%

  # then we do a left join. 
  # this introduces NA's for values (e.g. c1) that are not in dfA
  left_join(dfA, by = c("value" = "__ID"))%>%

  # Now we group by fk name (e.g. _ID0)
  group_by(fk_table, fk)%>%

  # And we count how often the result is not NA
  # an inner_join followed by counting the rows would be simpler
  # but then you don't get zero values as in the example
  summarise(intersects=sum(!is.na(col)))
```

This returns the following:

```
  fk_table    fk intersects
1      dfB  _ID0          0
2      dfB  _ID1          1
3      dfB  _ID2          2
4      dfB  _ID3          3
```

Only difference is that you don't have the pk and pk_table columns in the end result but I guess it won't be difficult to add this.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, thanks this looks great! I plan to add additional tables as well. I assume that I should add additional left_join commands directly after the one that you've written? Any idea about how to join all of the tables that I have? Now, all of the data frames are stored in a single list object. I think your answer still works even when I add multiple tables and the column names are not unique across all tables, right? That's the purpose of the `fk_table` column.

Comment: If you want to combine multiple tables you might want to see if you can divide the tables in two types based on their content. If this is possible it would be easier to simply paste the similar tables into single long table using the bind_rows() function. Then perform the join on the long tables you have created.